# Count rows in hierarchy structure including subtrees

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use recursive query to get number of events for every category including subcategories. I have 3 tables - ContentTabs (hierarchical table), Events and intermediate table RelEventsToContentTabs so it's simple many-to-many relationship. 
The problem is when I use a query such as one below I get number of Events for every category but without number of events for subcategories. 
I'm using SQL Server 2008.
Any ideas?

```
WITH ContentTabsStructure (Id, Name)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name,parentId FROM ContentTabs 
    WHERE Id =1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ct.Id, ct.Name,ct.parentId FROM ContentTabs AS ct
    INNER JOIN ContentTabsStructure AS cts
    ON ct.ParentId = cts.Id
)
    SELECT cts.id,cts.Name, Count(distinct e.id) as NumberOfEvents 
            FROM ContentTabsStructure cts
            INNER JOIN RelEventsToContentTabs etct
            ON cts.id = etct.contentTabId
            INNER JOIN Events e
            ON etct.eventId = e.id
            GROUP BY cts.id,cts.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include parentId also in CTE as:

```
WITH ContentTabsStructure (Id, Name,parentId)
```

to get subcategories for every category and then include some thing like below in selected columns to get number of events for subcategories:

```
, NumberOfSubCatagoryEvents = isnull(
( 
    Count(distinct e.id)
    FROM ContentTabsStructure cts1
    INNER JOIN RelEventsToContentTabs etct1
    ON cts1.id = etct1.contentTabId
    INNER JOIN Events e1
    ON etct1.eventId = e1.id
    where cts1.parentId<cts.parentId
    GROUP BY cts1.id,cts1.Name   

), 0 )
```